# Double quotes - $.parseJSON with Newtonsoft JsonConvert and MVC Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, escaping, json.net, double-quotes

I have a string with double quotes in ms-sql server :

[image]

I am passing it to view like so:

```
var json = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))';
var viewModelData = $.parseJSON(json);
```

In runtime it renders like so:

```
var json = '{"Description":"\"I am text in double quotes\""}';
```

But then $.parseJSON() throws an exception:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing a lot of unnecessary stuff here.
All I need is:

```
var viewModelData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
```